# Read a msg inside a bagfile

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the rosbag/Code API, we could see the msg by:

```
 import rosbag
 bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
 for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['chatter', 'numbers']):
     print msg
 bag.close()
```

When I try this, I see several msg entries. How could I select only one of entries to display?

[image: image description]

Like, for example. How could I get the data vector only?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287330/read-a-msg-inside-a-bagfile/) by [Teddy_NTU](https://answers.ros.org/users/33489/teddy_ntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-03**:
Please don't use an image to display text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of printing the whole message with `print msg`, do `print msg.data` or whichever field or fields you're interested in.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2